# Mustache PHP - How to load data from Database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, templates, mustache

In Mustache data is loaded from. json static files and I can't understand how can I load data from a MySQL DB.

Example: currently the data contained in the "partials" are loaded from a .json file but, of course, whatever application needs to load data from a database in dynamic way (mysql in my case).

How can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Giovanni

Comment: Can you post what you have tried that is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mustache PHP is only a templating engine. It's not an entire application with ready to go database bindings.

You need to write an application that instantiates Moustache templates and gives the necessary data.

```
$m = new Mustache_Engine;
echo $m->render(
         'Hello {{planet}}',
         array('planet' => 'World!')
     ); // "Hello World!"
```

The array with the `planet=> 'World!'` values is the data being passed to Moustache (in this case). You can load that data from a database and pass it to moustache as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, Mustache will help with the templating but you have to provide it the data to use and to get that data you'd need to have PHP connect to MySQL and return it. I'm guessing you're using PHP since it's in the title...

Hopefully this will help you get started. I'm using the data in the actor table from the [Sakila example database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html) for this example.

Sample data:

```
# actor_id, first_name, last_name, last_update
1, PENELOPE, GUINESS, 2006-02-15 04:34:33
2, NICK, WAHLBERG, 2006-02-15 04:34:33
3, ED, CHASE, 2006-02-15 04:34:33
4, JENNIFER, DAVIS, 2006-02-15 04:34:33
5, JOHNNY, LOLLOBRIGIDA, 2006-02-15 04:34:33
```

---

First, you need the php script that will fetch the data from MySQL. Use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) to convert the array returned by the `fetch_all()` method into a JSON string. By specifying that we want to get an associative array (`fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`) it will have "column name" => "value" pairs. `json_encode()` takes care of the rest.

```
<?php

//test.php
  $mysql = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, 'sakila');

  $query = "SELECT * FROM actor LIMIT 5";

  $result = $mysql->query($query);

  echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
?>
```

*There are other things you need to be aware of when querying and returning data from a database, especially if you pass user submitted data as part of your query, but that's beyond the scope of the question so I'm not worrying about it here.*

PHP script output:

```
[
  {
    "actor_id":"1",
    "first_name":"PENELOPE",
    "last_name":"GUINESS",
    "last_update":"2006-02-15 04:34:33"
  },
  {
    "actor_id":"2",
    "first_name":"NICK",
    "last_name":"WAHLBERG",
    "last_update":"2006-02-15 04:34:33"
  },
  {
    "actor_id":"3",
    "first_name":"ED",
    "last_name":"CHASE",
    "last_update":"2006-02-15 04:34:33"
  },
  {
    "actor_id":"4",
    "first_name":"JENNIFER",
    "last_name":"DAVIS",
    "last_update":"2006-02-15 04:34:33"
  },
  {
    "actor_id":"5",
    "first_name":"JOHNNY",
    "last_name":"LOLLOBRIGIDA",
    "last_update":"2006-02-15 04:34:33"
  }
]
```

You can then use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to load `test.php`. The data received is accessible to the callback function in our example via the `actorData` variable. Using the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method we can loop through each "row" within `actorData`, a JSON object, and tell Mustache to render each according to the template previously defined. Once rendered each row gets appended to the `#content` element.

```
<!--index.html-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/recipes/include/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/recipes/include/js/mustache.js"></script>
<script>
  var template = "<div><span>{{first_name}}</span> <span>{{last_name}}</span></div>";

    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('test.php',
        function (actorData) {

            $.each(actorData, function (i, actor) {
                var html = Mustache.render(template,
                actor);
                $('#content').append(html);
            });

        });
    });
</script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

*I'm including jQuery here in addition to Mustache.js*